# Updateable Data Grid using Linq to SQL in WinForms

Tags: vb.net, linq, datagrid

I'm populating a datagrid using Linq--standard kind of stuff (code below). For some reason however my ultraDataGrid is stuck in some kind of read-only mode. I've checked all the grid properties I can think of.  Is that a result of binding to a Linq data source?  Anyone have example code of an updatable grid that uses Linq?

```
db = New DataContext
myData = New dataClass
dataUltraGrid.DataSource = From table _
       In db.profiles _
        Select table.field1, table.field2...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:  use lambda expressions to filter the entity and bind directly to the entity.

Answer (score 2):

Your really not using a LinqDataSource control... your are binding to a List db.profiles your data grid doesn't know anything about updating or deleting or inserting by just being bound to that list, can I suggets this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="FooID">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FooID" HeaderText="FooID" InsertVisible="False" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="FooID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
                    SortExpression="Description" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ContextTypeName="YourDataContext" EnableDelete="True" 
            EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" TableName="Foos">
        </asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Comment: This is an example for ASP.  I'm doing winforms.  What would that logic look like?

Comment: ahh... sorry haven't done a win forms application in a while. I gave it a quick look and unfortunately there is no LinqDataSource control as with asp.net